# How to search for error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, x-editable

I'm using "Bootstrap Editable" with "in line editing".
I'm printing a table with data from MySQL.
Now i´d like to be able to edit a cell and update my database with PHP.

The "in line edit" script works fine.
But the mysql update doesn't.

Now, when i turn on "php error mode" or tries to "JS alert" my variables in post php, to check if they holds data i can't see any errors or alerts on the front page.
How can i read the error codes or alerts?

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
echo "<td><a href='#' id='element_ant' data-type='text' data-pk='".$row['id']."' data-url='php/posts.php' data-title='Anteckning..'>".$row['element_ant']."</a></td>";
```

**PHP**

```
if($_POST['name']=='element_ant'){
$id=$_POST['pk'];
$element_ant=$_POST['value'];

//Prepare query
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM table WHERE id=$id";
try{ 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $result = $stmt->execute();
} 
catch(PDOException $ex){
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
//Result from query
$row = $stmt->fetch();

//Deside insert or update
if($row[0]==0){
    $query = "INSERT INTO table(id,element_ant) VALUES(:id,:element_ant)"; 
}
else{
    $query = "UPDATE table SET element_ant = :element_ant WHERE id = :id";
}   

// Security measures
$query_params = array(':id' => $id,':element_ant' => $element_ant);

//Connect and execute
try {  
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex){
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready( function () {  
$('#element_ant').editable({
url : '../php/elements.php',
title : 'Enter comments'
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The `url` attribute is duplicated, i.e you have declared it as `data-url` in your HTML and in your Js code as `url:`. Decide which one is right and use either, not both.

2) In your php, there is `if($_POST['name']=='element_ant')`; you have to set it in your editable HTML element as such:

`<a href='#' id='element_ant' data-name="element_ant"`

When the **Editable** object is being saved, the `data-name` will be passed as a POST parameter `name`.

For Client-Side Debugging: [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)
For Server-Side Debugging: [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org)

Comment: @Mystereyos Thank you. 1) Should for ex. `data-url` be in both HTMl and JS, or just in one place?

Comment: One place. i recommend using it in the HTML, so that you can reuse that snippet of JS code

Comment: The scope of the question will be broad then. Errors could range from wrong url, to html mal formed, to js errors.. Try using firebug as suggested above for starters.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use some sort of logging framework , or you can write your own logging functions to log your error code on the file system.